# Environment variables in node js

Tags: node.js, security

Are nodejs environment variables accessible to hackers on a running process?

For example suppose I have a file called server.js, and I run the following command to start up the server:

```
SECRET_KEY=SECRET node server.js
```

Can a hacker extract the value of SECRET_KEY if he manages to break into into my server?

Comment: If the hacker had access to your server then he would have to do is stop the cmd command and check what the last run command was

Comment: also beware of "server side js" injection, if you use eval(), setTimeout(), setInterval(), Function() on user provided input, he could possibly extract env variables

Comment: If a hacker break into your server, knowing your `SECRET_KEY` is the least of your problem :) and so yes he can read any of your .js files.

Comment: How can i hold a secret key in memory so that an attacker cannot extract it? Slack says that they load their encryption key into memory, but I don't know how they do it..